# Joomla's triggerEvent not working

Tags: php, joomla

I tried to call the jooomla triggerEvent function for rsform Pro's payment plugin from an external php file. 
But I keep getting 500 errors and my server error log didn't cache the error code. 
Below is my code and I also added my reference. 
Please help me to find out the error source. 
Thank you in advance.

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', '../');
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );      
require_once (JPATH_BASE. '/plugins/system/rsfppayment/rsfppayment.php');
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');




  $updatedSubmissionId = 168;
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
    $mainframe->triggerEvent('rsfp_afterConfirmPayment', array($updatedSubmissionId));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to make your own function for your plugin then to use a function from another plugin. But I will give a short note on method to call plugins inside your own plugin code(latest for Joomla 3+):

Step 1: 
Call `JPluginHelper::importPlugin( 'plugingroup' );`

plugingroup can be system or plugin folder where rsfppayment plugins are located.

Step 2:

```
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
```

Step 3:

```
$results = $dispatcher->trigger( 'rsfp_afterConfirmPayment', array($updatedSubmissionId) );
```

Comment: The thing is, I was creating a new payment gateway extension for this plugin. So I still need to use this plugin feature such as sending emails.

For your code, I tried and there is no error but the functionality itself is not working.

Comment: There might be lot of other stuff in your code that may not have been set correctly. By the way which payment gateway you are trying to set up. They might be having their own php code?

Comment: I was setting easypay but all these payment setup and updating database are done and working. In that trigger function, only one function is involved and this is sending mail to the user and admin.

RSFormProHelper::sendSubmissionEmails($updatedSubmissionId);

I cannot call this class also. I guess I have to create my own function to sent out the email :( .

Comment: I have never used this form RSFormPro but looking at the class it seems its a helper class mostly in the helpers folder. If you include the helper class in your code it might work. But check that "/plugins/system/rsfppayment/rsfppayment.php" file does not already include "RSFormProHelper" class. Else you will get a class redaclartion error.

Comment: In some post I have seen they have used this path to get the RSFormProHelper Class. 
require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_rsform/helpers/rsform.php'; Include this code at top.

Comment: I found the source of error now. It just the function that i call used the query string of the requested url inside. Have no idea why they used it. Now it is okay and your code is working. Thank you Amit. :)

Answer (score 1):

The below code should do the trick - a 'little' more information can be found on the docs.joomla.org site https://docs.joomla.org/Triggering_content_plugins_in_your_extension.

```
// Note JDispatcher is deprecated in favour of JEventDispatcher in Joomla 3.x however still works.
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('system');
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher->trigger('rsfp_afterConfirmPayment', array($updatedSubmissionId));
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will check and try.